# Unable to create classic template with value override parameter in my dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

My scenario is I am calling a data-flow pipeline with cloud function, I had created classic template and called it sucessfully.
But my pipeline contains GCS input path harcoded in my code.

I want to pass it with API as parameters:{input:gcspath} in body of request at runtime. In order to do that
I searched in DOC it was telling i need to override value parameter, and I override valueparameter in my code  but when I am creating the template there is no template being created.May be my code is wrong
I am pasting the code below if anybody can check I missed something in it.
or if someone can paste small correct sample snippet.

------------------My Code-------------

```
import apache_beam as beam
# from apache_beam.io import fileio
import argparse
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from sys import argv 


PROJECT_ID = 'xxxxx-rnd'
# SCHEMA = 'sr:INTEGER,abv:FLOAT,id:INTEGER,name:STRING,style:STRING,ounces:FLOAT'
SCHEMA = 'High:STRING,Low:STRING,Open:STRING,Close:STRING,Volume:STRING,AdjClose:STRING'

def discard_incomplete(data):
    """Filters out records that don't have an information."""
    return len(data['abv']) > 0 and len(data['id']) > 0 and len(data['name']) > 0 and len(data['style']) > 0

def convert_types(data):
    """Converts string values to their appropriate type."""
    data['Date'] = str(data['Date']) if 'Date' in data else None
    data['High'] = str(data['High']) if 'High' in data else None
    data['Low'] = str(data['Low']) if 'Low' in data else None
    data['Open'] = str(data['Open']) if 'Open' in data else None
    data['Close'] = str(data['Close']) if 'Close' in data else None
    data['Volume'] = str(data['Volume']) if 'Volume' in data else None
    data['AdjClose'] = str(data['AdjClose']) if 'AdjClose' in data else None
    # data['Average'] = float(data['Average']) if 'Average' in data else None
    return data


def del_unwanted_cols(data):
    """Delete the unwanted columns"""
    del data['Date']
    # del data['brewery_id']
    return data
 
class WordcountOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        # Use add_value_provider_argument for arguments to be templatable
        # Use add_argument as usual for non-templatable arguments
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--input',
            default='gs://xxx/convertcsv.csv',
            help='Path of the file to read from')
        parser.add_argument(
            '--output',
            required=True,
            help='Output file to write results to.')

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(['--output', 'gs://xxx/results/output'],
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project='rightmechanics-rnd',
    job_name='dataflow-intro',
    temp_location='gs://xxx/valuetemp',
    region='us-central1'
    )
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
wordcount_options = pipeline_options.view_as(WordcountOptions)
(p  | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(wordcount_options.input, skip_header_lines =1)
    | 'SplitData' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(','))
    | 'FormatToDict' >> beam.Map(lambda x: {"Date": x[0], "High": x[1], "Low": x[2], "Open": x[3], "Close": x[4], "Volume": x[5], "AdjClose": x[6]}) 
    #    | 'DeleteIncompleteData' >> beam.Filter(discard_incomplete)
    | 'ChangeDataType' >> beam.Map(convert_types)
    | 'DeleteUnwantedData' >> beam.Map(del_unwanted_cols)
    #    | 'WriteToStorageBucket' >> beam.io.fileio.WriteToFiles(
    #        '{0}:beer.beer_data'.format(PROJECT_ID),
    #        schema=SCHEMA,
    #        write_disposition=beam.io.fileio.WRITE_APPEND
    #    )
    | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        '{0}:beer.beer_data2'.format(PROJECT_ID),
        schema=SCHEMA,
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
        method='FILE_LOADS'
        )
    )
result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the instructions and examples of creating a classic template [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates).

It says

> After you write your pipeline, you must create and stage your template file.

Is it possible that your cmd to create and stage the template file is not correct?

> After you create and stage your template, your next step is to execute the template.